# Problems with $SIG{WINCH} when using it in a module

Tags: perl, module, window, terminal, signals

When I use this module in a script, the `if ( $size_changed ) {` remains false when I've changed the terminal size.
When I copy the code from the module directly in a script (so that I don't have to load the module) it works as expected.
What could it be that loading the code as a module doesn't work?

```
use warnings;
use 5.014;
package My_Package;
use Exporter 'import';
our @EXPORT = qw(choose);

my $size_changed;
$SIG{WINCH} = sub { $size_changed = 1; };

sub choose {
    # ...
    # ...
    while ( 1 ) {
        my $c = getch();
        if ( $size_changed ) {
            write_screen();
            $size_changed = 0;
            next;
        }
        # ...
        # ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps somebody else has a SIGWINCH handler?

Comment: Does the signal get caught at all? What happens if you print to STDERR from the sig handler? `sub { $size_changed = 1; print STDERR "CAUGHT WINCH\n" };`

Comment: To address tchrist's question, you can do `print STDERR "refWINCH:|".ref($SIG{WINCH})."|\n";` right before assigning a handler in My_Package; then check if it prints "refWINCH:|CODE|" or "refWINCH:||"

Comment: Perl doesn't know the difference between a script and a module. It's all just Perl code to it. But by moving your code, you also added two other changes: You now execute the code of the module earlier than before, and you now have a block around the code. Neither of those makes a difference in the code you showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the reason: apart from this module I load a second module which does use `$SIG{WINCH}` too.
When I don't load the second module the `choose` subroutine works as expected.

Comment: If you make sure your code is loaded second, you could create a chain: `my $existing = $SIG{WINCH}; $SIG{WINCH} = sub { $existing->() if ref($existing); ... };`

Comment: See [`Signals::XSIG`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Signals::XSIG) as a possible workaround for multiple handlers attached to the same signal.

Comment: Yup: I tolja somebody else had run away with your wench.

Comment: @mob: With `Signals::XSIG` I have to hope that there is not other module loaded which uses the same Signal with the same index.

Comment: @sid_com Don't sweat it. There are very few modules so far that recognize the genius that is `Signals::XSIG`. ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Why are you modifying a variable then waiting for it in an infinite loop?

Wouldn't be better if you call that sub from signal handler directly?

$SIG{WINCH} = sub { print STDERR "WINCH!\n";choose();  };

This handler is in your module main secion, it is executed in complie time not execution time and only if you using use not require.

Maybe this is works in a module

```
local $size_changed;
BEGIN{
   $SIG{WINCH} = sub { $size_changed = 1; };
}
```

Just a guess: try to use Perl::Unsafe::Signals.

```
use Perl::Unsafe::Signals;
```

Comment: There's no reason to believe it's an infinite loop; the loop gets exited once the user provides a suitable input. He's got a sub that gets info from the user; it would be dumb to call it from the signal handler instead of where he wants to call it. The `local` would get undone before `$size_changed` ever gets used, so that's useless. `use` already adds a `BEGIN` block. There's no need for unsafe signals. There's no need to interrupt any XS/OS calls. So that leaves the debugging tip that was already given an hour ago.

Comment: *Never* run actual code other than trivial code in a signal handler. Signal handlers are called right in the middle of other stuff, like system calls, etc. Setting a global variable and responding to it in the loop is the correct way to do it.