# Is my `$SIG{WINCH}` save if I localize it?

Tags: perl, signals, localized

Some time ago I had problems with `$SIG{WINCH}` because I loaded two module which were both using `$SIG{WINCH}` [Problems with $SIG{WINCH} when using it in a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278201/problems-with-sigwinch-when-using-it-in-a-module).
Now I have tried to reconstruct this case but this time I put in one module the `$SIG{WINCH}` within a subroutine.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
package My_Package;
use Exporter 'import';
our @EXPORT = qw(choose);

sub choose {
    # ...
    my $size_changed;
    local $SIG{WINCH} = sub { $size_changed = 1; }; # edit: added "local"
    while ( 1 ) {
        my $c = getch();
        if ( $size_changed ) {
            write_screen();
            $size_changed = 0;
            next;
        }
        # ...
    }
}
```

Now it looks like it is working.
Am I save if I localize `$SIG{WINCH}` this way or did I forget something when reconstructing?

Comment: Are you actually localizing anything? You haven't used `local` or `my` or `our`, the keywords usually associated with such things. In Perl, variables remain global unless declared otherwise... You probably want `local $SIG{WINCH} = sub { $size_changed = 1; };` but I might be wrong.

Comment: It just occurred to me, while skimming perlipc, that I should ad `local`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works because your code immediately enters a `while` loop after setting the signal handler, so no other code gets to run (or set a new handler). When the while loop exits, your handler is unset and the old one is restored automatically thanks to `local`.

For more resilient code I would check to see if an existing signal handler exists, and call that. Otherwise any other module that has a SIGWINCH handler will be broken. E.g.

```
my $orig_sigwinch = $SIG{WINCH};
local $SIG{WINCH} = sub {
    $orig_sigwinch->() if $orig_sigwinch && ref $orig_sigwinch eq 'CODE';
    $size_changed = 1;
}
```

Note that this doesn't consider the case where `$orig_sigwinch` is a function name rather than a code reference.

Comment: Why is the handler unset when the while loop exits and not at the end of the `choose` routine?